# Angular 2: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://imgur-apiv3.p.mashape.com/. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, http, angular, http-headers, cors

I am trying to upload an image to the imgur api:  https://imgur-apiv3.p.mashape.com/.

But I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://imgur-apiv3.p.mashape.com/. A
>   wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header when the credentials flag is true. Origin
>   'http://mysite.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
>   withCredentials attribute.

What I find strange is that I do set this header:

```
  headers: Headers[] = [
    {
      name: 'X-Mashape-Key',
      value: 'XXX'
    },
    {
      name: 'Accept',
      value: 'application/json'
    },
    {
      name: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
      value: 'http://mysite.azurewebsites.net'
    },
    {
      name: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
      value: 'true'
    }
  ];

  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader(
    {
      url: URL,
      authToken: 'Client-ID XXX',
      headers: this.headers
    }
  );
```

In the debug console in chrome I can see:

```
> Accept:application/json Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,no;q=0.4
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://mysite.azurewebsites.net
> Authorization:Client-ID XXX Cache-Control:no-cache
> Connection:keep-alive Content-Length:1419511
> Content-Type:multipart/form-data;
```

Also on the config in Azure portal I have set:

ALLOWED ORIGINS

```
https://imgur-apiv3.p.mashape.com
```

Also uploaded a web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://mysite.azurewebsites.net"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Seems to me I have setup CORS every single place I can think of, what am I doing wrong?

Is it because it's a HTTP site connecting to a HTTPS API endpoint?

Comment: I am having the same/similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232527/configure-cors-xmlhttprequest-to-allow-cross-site-access-to-username-password-pr

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue now and then, and sometimes it turns out that the URL string could leads to the problem. Maybe there is a typo in the string, or maybe something wrong with the path which cause the exact API can not be found with the given URL.

Please try to check the URL string before put the effort into the CORS related work.

Sometimes it solve the problem pretty quick by doing so, and the error message of "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" seems not quite accurate here.